# Problems with Layout Constraints: NSArray is not a subtype of NSLayoutConstraint

Tags: ios, swift, visual-format-language

I seem to be having issues with `NSLayoutConstraint`. From what I can gather (and I hope I am wrong here), the `.addConstrait()` function is supposed to take variable of type `NSLayoutContraint` - but `NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat()` is generating `NSArray`s?

This doesnt make sense to me. Ive tried translating the `NSArray` over to a `NSLayoutConstraint` but I get errors doing that. Surely the output from `NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat()` would be the same type as is expected by `.addConstrait()`??

If not why not? and what is the best way to solve this issue?

Here is the code:

```
    let swiftViews:Dictionary[String: UIView] = ["status":status]
    let swiftMetrics = ["standardWidth":200]
    let views:NSDictionary = swiftViews as NSDictionary
    let metrics:NSDictionary = swiftMetrics as NSDictionary

    let statusHorzVFLCons = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|-[status]-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: metrics, views: views)

    self.view.addConstraint(statusHorzVLFCons)
```

This last line produces the error:

```
'NSArray' is not a subtype of 'NSLayoutConstraint'
```

Can someone point out where I am going wrong.

Comment: Check out the lib Cartography for all your contraint needs: https://github.com/robb/Cartography

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`constraintsWithVisualFormat(_:options:metrics:views:)` returns `NSArray` of `NSLayoutConstraint`.

Just use `addConstraints(_:)` instead of `addConstraint(_:)`

```
self.view.addConstraints(statusHorzVLFCons)
                       ^
```

Answer (score 1):

The `addConstraint` method expect a single constraint, however the `constraintsWithVisualFormat` returns an `NSArray` of zero or more constraints.

Try adding an s.

```
[self addConstraints:/*your NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: call */];
```

Apple's naming conventions can usually help you out here. Notice that `constraintsWithVisualFormat` is plural while `addConstraint` was singular (and `addConstraints` is plural).